# Data being stored in User class instead of UserProfile

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I'm trying to create a custom class `Employee` that uses the default authentication. I am able to successfully register but the fields associated with Django's User class are stored in `User` while my custom fields are stored in `Employee`. How can I get everything stored in `Employee`?

This is my `forms.py`:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')

class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('sales', 'hours')
```

And my `models.py`:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    sales = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    hours = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Like I said, I would prefer to use the default authentication and therefore avoid using a custom backend

Comment: Something like `class Employee(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin): ... objects = UserManager()` may do the trick. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/

Answer (score 0):

What you're using is generally called a User Profile which will not store the added fields in the same table (which you have found out). MOre info on that can be found in [Extending existing user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

What you're wanting to do (and the method that I typically need to use in my projects) is [Substitute a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model). It is a bit more complicated, but once you get the hang of it it's not too bad. It will allow you to store all your User fields in one table instead of in separate tables/models.